# MariaDB 11.0.2 fails to start after upgrade from 10.11.4

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, mariadb

I am on Debian Bullseye and just upgraded (or at least attempted to upgrade) MariaDB from 10.11.4 to 11.0.2.

Unfortunately, the service fails to start now. All I'm getting through `systemctl status mariadb.service` and `journalctl -xe` is pretty unhelpful, like (respectively):

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 11.0.2 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: inactive (dead) (Result: signal) since Fri 2023-06-16 22:05:13 CEST; 4s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 6291 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE>
    Process: 6292 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCC>
    Process: 6294 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/>
    Process: 6323 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=killed, si>
   Main PID: 6323 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
        CPU: 144ms
```

```
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max processes             128262               128262               processes
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max open files            32768                32768                files
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max locked memory         524288               524288               bytes
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max pending signals       128262               128262               signals
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max nice priority         0                    0
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max realtime priority     0                    0
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Core pattern: core
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX mariadbd[6323]: Kernel version: Linux version 5.10.0-23-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) >
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 6.
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'signal'.
Jun 16 22:05:10 XXXXX systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 11.0.2 database server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6703 and the job result is failed.
```

I would try to debug this further through error logs, unfortunately MariaDB somehow refuses to log errors even though I set `log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log` and hunted down all instances of `skip_log_error` as well as `syslog` that seem to be preconfigured in the Debian config files.

Now, if I rename `/var/lib/mysql` and re-initialize it, the service works. However, this isn't a solution for me since I need to recover the data and *of course* I didn't back it up this one time.

Any ideas or potential solutions?

Comment: recover data? install back previous version which will hopefully start. dump all databases, dump privileges, upgrade, clean slate, restore dumped databases and grants.

Comment: Unfortunately the downgraded DB wasn't starting either by default. I needed to do a fresh installation and then copy over the raw DB files one by one without even dumping or converting them.
Funnily enough even the system DBs worked so I literally didn't need to re-configure a single thing including privileges.

Comment: [with debug info packages](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/#installing-debug-info-packages-from-mariadbs-debian-or-ubuntu-repository) you can run `sudo -u mysql gdb --args /usr/sbin/mariadbd` then `bt -frame-arguments all full` after the crash to [report a bug](https://jira.mariadb.org). Generally if log_error is blank it ends up at stdout/stderr which ends up easily in the systemd journal for easy access.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer for all future users but I managed to recover all data by first downgrading to a fresh installation (backing up the previous data directory) and then copying over databases and other files from the data directory one-by-one.
Funnily enough this resulted in forwards compatibility as well when proceeding this way.
I believe the issue was that the upgrade scripts failed if I had to do them on all databases at once - I got a couple large ones, around 50GB and 25GB respectively, and these might have been blocking the upgrade.

Comment: normally an upgrade doesn't need to look through all tables or database.  144ms of CPU time doesn't seem to correspond to any processing issue. A simple downgrade would have probably sufficed. It sounds definitely like it was a bug.